# Core Data Relationship settings

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, datamodel

Im creating an app which got the entities "Plan" and "Tool". A "Tool" must be unique and tools get linked to different plans. For example Plan "A" got the tools "a", "b", and "c". And another Plan "B" got the tools "b", "c" and "d". So "b" and "c" are both in "A" and "B". So a Tool can be linked to more plans.

How can I do this with the core data relationships? 
I tried some different settings and observed the database with "DB Browser for SQLite" but its not working as Id like to.

Example:

[image]

Which settings must my relationships have?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Creating both entities in the Code Data datamodel and creating a "tools" "to-many" relationship in Plan and a "plans" "to-many" relationship in Tool and marking each other as inverse should work.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I did not know how to interpret the database structure in my database browser. Due to your comment I tried it again and then it turned out that it already worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW8):

> Many-to-Many Relationships
>
> You define a many-to-many relationship using two to-many
>   relationships. The first to-many relationship goes from the first
>   entity (the source entity) to the second entity (the destination). The
>   second to-many relationship goes from the second entity (the original
>   destination entity) to the first entity (the original source entity).
>   You then set each to be the inverse of the other.

In your case it should look like this:

[image: Model Diagram]

Here you see the relationship properties:

[image: Relationship Properties 1]

[image: Relationship Properties 2]

Again, from Apple's documentation:

> IMPORTANT
>
> You must define many-to-many relationships in both directions—that is,
>   you must specify two relationships, each being the inverse of the
>   other. You can’t just define a to-many relationship in one direction
>   and try to use it as a many-to-many. If you do, you will end up with
>   referential integrity problems.